# Phonegap run android error on Windows 8

Tags: android, node.js, cordova

I'm trying to run phonegame on Windows 8 and I get the following error when I type **phonegap run android**. Any ideas how to solve it? I have everything ready, nodejs, cordova and etc.

> C:\Users\almeidamarcell\my-app>phonegap run android [phonegap]
>   detecting Android SDK environment... [phonegap] using the local
>   environment [phonegap] adding the Android platform...    [error] An
>   error occured during creation of android sub-project.
>
> C:\Users\almeidamarcell.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.
>   js:126
>                       throw e;
>                             ^ Error: Failed to run 'java -version', make sure your java environment is set up including JDK and JRE. Your
>   JAVA_HOME variable is undefined Error: Command failed: 'java' is not
>   recognized as an internal or external comma nd,
>
> operable program or batch file.
>
> ```
> at C:\Users\almeidamarcell\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\lib\check_
> ```
>
> reqs.js:62:22
>       at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:641:7)
>       at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
>       at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
>       at Socket. (child_process.js:956:11)
>       at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
>       at Pipe.close (net.js:465:12)
>
> C:\Users\almeidamarcell\my-app>phonegap run android

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't have java installed in your computer.If it is installed, path is not set properly. Give the path of Ant too.  You need to add Android SDk and prepare Android Targets via SDK manager before going through this.

I hope following reference might help you.

```
-JAVA_HOME (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51)
-ANT_HOME (C:\Program Files\apache\apache-ant-1.9.3)
-ANDROID_HOME (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. I did everything you said, but now I get this error:

http://pastebin.com/zGgLGWXr

Comment: I fixed the problem above following the ant installing guide here http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html. Now I got anoooother error. This I really don't know how to solve it.

http://pastebin.com/Yv01Ku2s

Comment: it sounds like the ant or java isn't properly installed. have you tried "javac" and "ant-v" or "ant-version" in cmd? If cmd shows errors, then you have to fixed them first. Make sure you have installed android-sdk up to API19..